# Use ref as the model of vee-validate

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

I'm trying to use vee-validate with a `ref`.

Let's say I have a form with fields `name` and `collectionId`. I'd like to be able to have something like:

```js
const fields = ref({name: '', collectionId: null})
```

And after, pass the reactive variable to `useForm` (or something similar). I'm doing this because the `collectionId` is controlled by a custom component.

I tried syncing the `collectionId` with a ref using watch, but I was having some odd behaviors and the code was becoming too complex with imperative calls.